# mac osx emacs terminal `C-M e` not works but `C-M a` works

Tags: terminal-emacs

in mac osx 's terminal.app, open emacs.

key binding `C-M a` works, will call `c-beginning-defun`
but, `C-M e` does not work: nothing is displayed, and `C-h k` for this key also shows nothing.

Comment: Does this link help any?  https://osxdaily.com/2013/02/01/use-option-as-meta-key-in-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: I use the "Use Option as Meta key" option in Terminal, and both `C-M-a` and `C-M-e` work for me. Is it possible you have another app that's capturing that hotkey or a variant of it?

Comment: Which version of emacs are you using? Is it the one that came with older versions of  MacOS, or a version you installed?

Comment: @amitp GNU Emacs 26.2, I installed it

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable to you, but @amitp's tip about having another app that's capturing the key was on the money. For me it was the [magnet app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12), so make sure that you don't have any globally running apps with funky keybinds.